# Nonhomogeneous heat equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I really don't know how to start to solve it:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
u_{t}=ku_{xx}-\lambda^{2}u, & x\in(0,\ell), t>0 \\
u(0,t)=u(\ell,t)=0, & t>0 \\
u(x,0)=h(x), & x\in(0,\ell)
\end{array}\right.$$

I know there are some tips, like using some function $v(x,t)$ to solve the "original" heat equation (the homogeneous one), but I didn't find anything about how to start solving a problem like this one.

I just need to know what are the first steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the integrating factor method borrowed from first order linear ODEs, your equation becomes $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(e^{\lambda^2 t}u)=k \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} \left ( e^{\lambda^2 t} u \right )$. Thus $e^{\lambda^2 t} u$ solves the ordinary heat equation.

Comment: I didn't learn this... where can I find something about it?

Comment: Beat me to it! @mvfs314 this is the same technique used to solve first order linear ODEs, repackaged in a slightly different way than you might have learned it. I suggest reading up on that.

Comment: @mvfs314 In the ODE context you can find it in any standard source on elementary differential equations, such as Boyce and DiPrima. In the PDE context I don't think this trick is usually explicitly taught, but is rather relegated to exercises, since it is really just a simple extension of the ODE version (since the integrating factor, being only time-dependent, looks like a constant to the spatial derivatives).

Comment: Oh ok, as I thought haha thanks!